# Navigation bar issue with landscape mode

Tags: navigation, uicollectionview, screen-orientation, landscape-portrait, device-orientation

I am applying the landscape mode to only one view controller. In that view controller, I am using the collections view. Everything is working fine in portrait mode. In landscape, mode data shows perfectly except for the navigation bar title and back button.
I am attaching the images

Portrait Mode

[image]

Landscape mode

[image]

I am using the below code for the landscape mode

```
extension UIApplication {

    class func getTopViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        
        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
            return getTopViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
        }

        if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
                return getTopViewController(base: selected)
            }
        }

        if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return getTopViewController(base: presented)
        }

        return base
    }

}
```

Created protocol

```
protocol Rotatable {}
```

and calling

```
class ComparePlans: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, Rotatable {
```

I don't know exactly what the issue is. I tried different ways. Any help would appreciate it.

My storyboard page image

[image]

Comment: Did you check the view hierarchy? What's that unwanted black view?

Comment: @lazarevzubov My issue is that black view. I am attaching my storyboard screen with pinnings.

Comment: It was clear even before. Do you know what is view hierarchy and how to debug it? E.g., https://medium.com/stacc/utilizing-the-debug-view-hierarchy-to-better-understand-your-apps-ui-c8655f6d34e9.

Comment: Thanks, @lazarevzubov. I get to know the unwanted black view with the help of the view hierarchy.